# SQL Calculating decimal average instead of int

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, average, distinct

I have a table like following:

Activity table:

```
+---------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| user_id | session_id | activity_date | activity_type |
+---------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | 1          | 2019-07-21    | open_session  |
| 1       | 1          | 2019-07-21    | scroll_down   |
| 1       | 1          | 2019-07-21    | end_session   |
| 2       | 4          | 2019-07-21    | open_session  |
| 2       | 4          | 2019-07-22    | send_message  |
| 2       | 4          | 2019-07-22    | end_session   |
| 3       | 2          | 2019-07-22    | open_session  |
| 3       | 2          | 2019-07-22    | send_message  |
| 3       | 2          | 2019-07-22    | end_session   |
| 3       | 5          | 2019-07-22    | open_session  |
| 3       | 5          | 2019-07-22    | scroll_down   |
| 3       | 5          | 2019-07-22    | end_session   |
| 4       | 3          | 2019-06-20    | open_session  |
| 4       | 3          | 2019-06-20    | end_session   |
+---------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I am trying to calculate the average number of sessions per user for a period of 30 days ending 2019-07-28. I am working on this problem in SQL Server.

My query is

```
SELECT 
       ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT(session_id))/COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) ,2 ) average_sessions_per_user
FROM Activity
WHERE activity_date >= DATEADD(day, -30, 2019-07-27)
```

The output returns 1. The correct output should be 1.33.

I couldn't figure out why my output is 1. If I check output for `COUNT(DISTINCT(session_id))` and `COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id))` separately, returns are 4 and 3 which is correct. However, once I divided them like the query above, it is not working properly.

Comment: A quick google will show you that in SQL Server if you divide by an int you get an int result. Convert you values to decimal before dividing and you'll get a decimal result.

Comment: Thanks Dale! This answers my question. I wasn't realize it was due to integer divide by integer.Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `COUNT` returns an integer, so dividing two `COUNT` values is an integer division, which will return an integer. Adding a multiplication by 1.0 makes the operation floating point, which then returns the expected result:

```
SELECT 
       ROUND(1.0*COUNT(DISTINCT(session_id))/COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) ,2 ) average_sessions_per_user
FROM Activity
WHERE activity_date >= DATEADD(day, -30, '2019-07-27')
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/149a0/5)

Note also that your date inside `DATEADD` needs to be enclosed in quotes (see the above query and demo).

Comment: Thanks Nick! This answers my question!

Comment: @BonjugaLewis, Please mark it answer. so, it will be helpful for others in future